# How can I use salt-mine when using salt-ssh

Tags: salt-stack

I have a saltstack state which requires accessing the salt mine for it to execute correctly. This has been working fine, but we have recently switched to using salt-ssh and it is producing the following error

```
TypeError encountered executing example_token: 'FunctionWrapper' object is not callable
```

This mine function is set up in my pillar as follows

```
mine_functions:
  example_token:
    - mine_function: cp.get_file_str
    - file:///tmp/example.txt
```

This is called in the state using

```
salt['mine.get'](minion_host_name, 'example_token')[minion_host_name]
```

Like I mentioned this has always worked when calling `salt '*' state.apply`

But after switching to `salt-ssh -i '*' state.apply`

Also switching to salt-ssh was out of my hands and going back is not an option. I have also tried declaring the functions in the roster rather than the pillar but produces the same result

Comment: "going back is not an option." - that's unfortunate. Salt-SSH has a lot of limitations. A full Salt minion should always be preferred.

Comment: What version of salt are you using? This looks like it was fixed years ago - https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/27808

Comment: Yeah saw that issue, 2019.2, so that fix should be included

Comment: 2019.2 has multiple very severe security issues. You need to upgrade to (ideally) 3004.1.